# Fortran equivalent of Class

Tags: oop, fortran

In my programme, I require a mulitidimensional array, in which the length of second and third dimension depend on the index of the first dimension. This is not directly possible with normal array in Fortran 90. Is there a equivalent of Class (in this sense) in Fortran that I can use here ?

Comment: Is it strictly required to use a 25 year old Standard of Fortran, or are you at liberty to choose a more recent version?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt : I am using FORTRAN 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using **derived types**:

```
type myType
  integer :: index
  integer,allocatable :: arr(:,:)
end type
```

You can assign the scalar by

```
type(myType) :: var
var%index = 10
```

and similarly allocate the array:

```
allocate( var%arr( var%index, var%index ) )
```

Comment: What does % mean here ?

Comment: With `%` you access elements of the derived type in Fortran.

Comment: If I have the defintion of some type in the program, can I define a variable of that type in the subroutine too (without having to define the type again in subroutine) ?

Comment: If you put the derived type declaration into a module (and `use` that module), yes.